# Spring Bean Factory

Tags: spring, javabeans

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> Table [basket] contains physical column name [user_id] referred to by
> multiple logical column names: [user_id], [userId]

I'm having this problem and this is my class:

```
package sukhrob.project.firstproject.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Where;
import sukhrob.project.firstproject.entities.enums.BasketTypeEnum;
import sukhrob.project.firstproject.entities.template.AbsEntity;

import java.util.UUID;


@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
@SQLDelete(sql = "update basket set deleted=true where id=?")
@Entity(name = "basket")
public class Basket extends AbsEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private UUID userId;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private BasketTypeEnum basketType;

    private String description;

}
```

i'm having this error. can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the column `userId`

```
public class Basket extends AbsEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private User user;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private BasketTypeEnum basketType;

    private String description;

}
```

This will be automatically generate using the `@JoinColumn` annotation